# How can I convet MutableMap<String, Any?> to vararg values: Pair<String, Any?>?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

The following code is from "Kotlin for Android Developers", you can access it at https://github.com/antoniolg/Kotlin-for-Android-Developers

In order to insert a row data into `CityForecastTable.NAME`, I have to pass a `vararg` values by *Source Code* `fun SQLiteDatabase.insert`

**1:**  The author make a extension `toVarargArray()` to convert a `MutableMap<String, Any?>` to `Pair<String, Any?>`, I don't know whether there is a better way to do that. Do I need to use a extension function?

**2:**  The author have to use the code `it.value!!` in Code C , I don't know if the code `fun <K, V : Any> Map<K, V?>.toVarargArray(): Array<out Pair<K, V?>> = map({ Pair(it.key, it.value) }).toTypedArray()` is right?

**3:** I don't know whether the app will crash when I insert a row data of which a column include null value.

```
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.*
class ForecastDb(private val forecastDbHelper: ForecastDbHelper = ForecastDbHelper.instance,
                 private val dataMapper: DbDataMapper = DbDataMapper()) : ForecastDataSource {

    fun saveForecast(forecast: ForecastList) = forecastDbHelper.use {           

         //dataMapper.convertFromDomain(forecast) will return CityForecast object 
         with(dataMapper.convertFromDomain(forecast)) {
            insert(CityForecastTable.NAME, *map.toVarargArray())           
        }
    }

}


class CityForecast(val map: MutableMap<String, Any?>, val dailyForecast: List<DayForecast>) {
    var _id: Long by map
    var city: String by map
    var country: String by map

    constructor(id: Long, city: String, country: String, dailyForecast: List<DayForecast>)
            : this(HashMap(), dailyForecast) {
        this._id = id
        this.city = city
        this.country = country
    }
}
```

**Code C**

```
fun <K, V : Any> Map<K, V?>.toVarargArray(): Array<out Pair<K, V>> =
        map({ Pair(it.key, it.value!!) }).toTypedArray()
```

**Source Code**

```
fun SQLiteDatabase.insert(tableName: String, vararg values: Pair<String, Any?>): Long {
    return insert(tableName, null, values.toContentValues())
}
```

Comment: Isn't quite easy to test if the app will crash?

Answer (score 3):

You have pretty much everything there

Use the asterisk `*` operator also known as spread operator to spread your array to `vararg` inside function.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs

Add ? to the value and you are ready to go

```
fun <K, V : Any> Map<K, V?>.toVarargArray() = map { it.key to it.value }.toTypedArray()

    insert("", *mapOf("k" to "v").toVarargArray())
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the code `fun <K, V : Any> Map<K, V?>.toVarargArray(): Array<out Pair<K, V?>> = map({ Pair(it.key, it.value) }).toTypedArray()`  right?

Comment: I don't know whether the app will crash when I insert a row data of which a column include null value.

Comment: Thanks! will the code crash if `V?` is null  to invoke `it.value` at `fun <K, V : Any> Map<K, V?>.toVarargArray() = map { it.key to it.value }.toTypedArray()` ?

Answer (score 2):

1. No, you do not really need an extension function for that. It may make sense to have something in place if you are calling the `insert`-method (or any other which requires arrays instead of a `Map`) often. However depending on what you call more often, you may rather supply an extension function for the specific method with the `Map` as parameter instead.

   If you do not want to have the extension function you can call the following directly (if you aleady have a map):

   ```
   *map.map { it.key to it.value }.toTypedArray()
   ```
2. I wonder why the author allows `Any?` on the `CityForecast`-class as values but then decides to use `value!!`. I would rather recommend either using `Any`, that way no `null` values are allowed or otherwise falling back to a default, e.g. `value?:""`. Note that if you use `Any`, you probably need to ensure that your data in the database is not containing any `null`-values (column created with `NOT NULL` constraint).
3. You really should try it out. If it crashes you get familiar on how to deal with errors. I assume that it crashes (or at least throws a `NullPointerException` somewhere ;-)) if you use `null` values in the map and keep the mentioned extension function as then the `value!!`-call will fail. And note: you can always come back here to ask new questions, if there is an issue you can't resolve or you do not find any good sources for it.

Comment: Thanks! For 1, could you show me some code instead of `*map.toVarargArray()` in  `insert(CityForecastTable.NAME, *map.toVarargArray())` ?

Comment: Basically you can just call what is written in the extension function. Note that I do not know the method signature of `insert`, but I think the following will already suffice: `insert(CityForecastTable.NAME, "k" to "v", "otherkey" to "othervalue", /*alternatively*/ Pair("k2", "v2"))`

Comment: Ok. I know the signature if it's the one you posted, but with the mobile writing some comments it just disappears ;-) so the mentioned code in the comment suffices already.

Comment: Thank! I hope to  convet `MutableMap<String, Any?> ` to `vararg values: Pair<String, Any?>`  as parameter of  `insert` function.  At present, I think that extension function `fun <K, V : Any> Map<K, V?>.toVarargArray(): Array<out Pair<K, V>> =
        map({ Pair(it.key, it.value!!) }).toTypedArray()` is not good.

Comment: Well, it's nearly ok. I don't trust the `it.value!!`. Why shouldn't I be allowed to insert `null`-values (except the database column has `NOT NULL` declared). If you don't want to use the extension function, but you want to use the map, then you can still write: `*map.map { it.key to it.value }.toTypedArray()`.